# NSString drawInRect: is clipping ascenders

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

I want to draw blocks of text using `[NSString drawInRect: withAttributes:]`. However I found that when the font has ascenders that extend more than the default line height (some fonts have that, often the decorative ones), they are clipped at the top of the rect.

I can't use `drawAtPoint:` as far as I know, because I need line wrapping.

I played with various attributes like `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` to move the text down a bit in the rect, but nothing worked.

With a specific font that I have to work with, even the normal digits extend beyon the rect that way, and so every digit is clipped.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: As I know, text is clipped because you give the string a smaller size than it needs to display. How about increasing height of `rect`?

Comment: No, the clipping occurs at the top. If the rect is too small, it would clip at the bottom. The clipping occurs even occurs (on the first line only) when there are multiple lines of text.